# git pull deletes my partner's files

Tags: git, bitbucket

I don't have much experience using git and I couldn't find the solution on-line.

I am trying to coordinate a project with one more partner using git. We opened a bitbucket account where I created the repository. My partner used `git clone` to copy the repository to his local PC and everything seemed fine.

Now I made some changes, staged them by doing `git add [my staged files]` and then committed and pushed.

My partner tried to get the new code by doing `git pull`. However for some reason all the files that were cloned before to his PC disappeared and all that is left are the new recently staged files I just pushed.

Why does `git pull` behave this way? When I checkout the git repository on bitbucket it seems to be fine. Why were all the unchanged files deleted? Is it because they were never tracked or something? Seems weird...

Comment: He should do his development on his own branch.

Comment: Regarding this ..Is it because they were never tracked or something?  as your partner have cloned it from git, s all the files are automatically being tracked...    while regarding the entire question it totally looks wierd and i feel this is some manual fault..just perform the same steps again and give a try

Comment: Make your colleague run `git ls-tree --full-tree HEAD` in their work tree (this should be run from the console, after `cd`-ing to the project work tree first). Then do it yourself and compare the results. This command prints whatever Git thinks is recorded in the current branch's tip commit. So if the files which "were deleted" are missing from the output, they're really missing, for sure, as Git does not track them.

Comment: Another thing to check is to fire up `gitk --all` and closely inspect the situation.

Comment: Also note that what `git pull` does depends on how it was called, and also on the local repository's settings.

Answer (score 0):

While fetching data from remote, use

git pull --rebase

It will remove your locally committed changes, fetches data from remote and applies your changes on top of that..

Also before you pull anything make sure you have committed your changes..